# Getting the <img> tag in an HTML using PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

I have am output that has something like this:

```
<img src="location-of-image.png" style="width:100px;height:100px" title='smpl'/>
<p>sampe sample sampple</p><br />when? how?.
```

My problem here is that I only want to get

```
<img src="location-of-image.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;" title='smpl'/>
```

and remove

```
<p>sampe sample sampple</p><br />when? how?.`
```

So my expected output should be only like this:

```
<img src="location-of-image.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;" title='smpl'/>
```

How would I do that in PHP? 
I know this is easier to be done in javascript/jquery, but I want it in PHP.

Comment: Is the img tag the first tag of the input string?

Comment: Are your tags always split over 2 lines?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP DOM:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<img src="location-of-image.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;"    title='sampletitle' /><p>sampe sample sampple</p>');

$doc = $doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str  =  '<img src="location-of-image.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;" title='sampletitle' /><p>sampe sample sampple</p><br />when? how?.';

$toBeReplaced   =  '<p>sampe sample sampple</p><br />when? how?.';


$body = str_replace($toBeReplaced, "", $str);
```

Comment: The <img src='blah blah' /> is dynamic, it changes every time depending on a user output. All is dynamic in here, above was just an example.

Comment: Can u capture the dynamic text then pass this text to this variable $toBeReplaced=$your dynamic text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('^(<img.*?/>).*$', 
             '$1',
             '<img src="location-of-image.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;" title="sampletitle" /><p>sampe sample sampple</p><br />when? how?.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figure it out.

Here's my answer, a very obvious and easy solution:

```
$str = '<img src="location-of-image.png" style="width:100px;height:100px" title='smpl'/ <p>sampe sample sampple</p><br />when? how?.'

$str = strip_tags( $str, "<img>"); #For safety precaution.

$first = strpos($str, '<img ');
$last = strpos($str, '/>');
echo "<".substr( $str ,1,$last+1 );
```

Feels like i'm getting this answer right.

Thanks for everyone who answered! :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use regular expression to filter out the  tag you want.

Comment: This is pretty worthless as an answer. It's like saying "you can use programming to solve the problem".

Comment: I know Regex is worthless. But I dont know any other alternative yet.

Comment: @Hammerite The rule is don't use regex to manipulate *arbitrary* HTML, but if the OP's string always follows the same format (i.e. it's regular) then regex works just fine.

Comment: @KishoreK If you know your answer is crap, why did you answer at all?

Comment: @Juhana read my comment again! Not everyone can give the best solution. Anyone can express their ides even if its crappy. You cant say them not to answer at all.